# caret: Error when using anything but LOOCV with rpart

Tags: r

I'm trying to use the R caret module for model generation and I want to use some cross-validation function. I found out that the only cross validation function which works together with `rpart` is `LOOCV` (leave one out cross validation).

The following code throws the error:

```
library(cart)
data(trees)
formula=Volume~Girth+Height
train(formula, data=trees,  method='rpart')
```

> Warning message: In nominalTrainWorkflow(dat = trainData, info =
>   trainInfo, method = method,  :   There were missing values in
>   resampled performance measures.

What does this error mean and how do I make it go away? I searched on the internet, not a single hit for this error-message. I traced the error down to the `rpart` model generation. It somehow outputs this error message, all other mode-generation-methods work fine!

Everything works fine if I use `LOOCV`.

I traced the warning down to the [workflows.R](http://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/caret/R/workflows.R?view=markup&root=caret) file, but I do not understand why this warning gets thrown.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.15.0 (2012-03-30)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_GB.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_GB.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_GB.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=C                 LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods  
[8] base     

other attached packages:
 [1] earth_3.2-3           plotrix_3.4           plotmo_1.3-1         
 [4] leaps_2.9             doMC_1.2.5            multicore_0.1-7      
 [7] iterators_1.0.6       forecast_3.20         RcppArmadillo_0.3.0.2
[10] Rcpp_0.9.10           fracdiff_1.4-1        tseries_0.10-28      
[13] zoo_1.7-7             quadprog_1.5-4        caret_5.15-023       
[16] foreach_1.4.0         cluster_1.14.2        reshape_0.8.4        
[19] plyr_1.7.1            lattice_0.20-6        mda_0.4-2            
[22] class_7.3-3           rpart_3.1-52          data.table_1.8.0     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] codetools_0.2-8 compiler_2.15.0 grid_2.15.0
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using the R Mailinglist and the help of the `caret` author I found out the following solution:

If for some reason the model which is generated is constant the error occurs. Constant means in this case that for all input values the model always yields the same value. In this case, the calculation of R^2 fails. R^2 is calculated per default by caret. As caret does not use the R^2 value for model selection, you can skip this error.

Two questions remain:

- It is not clear to me why the R^2 calculation fails if the model is constant. The code in `caret` explicitely fails if there are not at least two different values in the model prediction. I replaced the R^2 calculation with a selfwritten one which does not have these limits.
- The question why rpart sometimes generates a constant model is still open. Especially why it only generates constant models for other cross validations than LOOCV.

In short: You can ignore the warning and if you need, write your own R^2 to fix the warning.

Comment: Thanks theomega for sharing the answer with SO. I am running into the same problem now when fitting nnet, knn and svmRadial. What do you mean by R^2 in this context? (and how did you edit your own?). Did you make any progress on the two questions that you pose above?

Comment: Well, caret calculates several metrics, including MAPE and R^2 for the models. The R^2 calculation throws an error if your model is constant (predicts the same value for all independent variables). The R^2 function used by caret can not be used for constant models. There are other R^2 definitions which work. I used one of them. You should keep in mind that there is not one(!) R^2 definition but several which lead to different values and restrictions.